# (Sensenet) How to Add File in 'Allowed child types' from Dotnet Client(sn-client-dotnet)?

Tags: c#, sensenet

I can create workspace by using this code:

> var myWorkspace = Content.CreateNew("/Root/Sites/Default_Site", "Workspace", "MyWorkspace");
>    await myWorkspace.SaveAsync();

How to set myWorkspace using dotnet client to have File in 'Allowed child types'?

Answer (score 0):

`AllowedChildTypes` is a field of the workspace content, so you can set its value like other field values. The value should be an array of strings (array of content type names).

```
content["AllowedChildTypes"] = ["File"];
await content.SaveAsync();
```

There's also an OData action for adding a content type to a content's AllowedChildTypes, its name is `AddAllowedChildTypes` and it should get a contentType array (string array of content type names) as parameter.

```
   dynamic workspace = await Content.LoadAsync(workspace);

    Task<dynamic> task = workspace.AddAllowedChildTypes(new {contentTypes = ["File"]});
    var result = await task;
```

https://community.sensenet.com/docs/built-in-odata-actions-and-functions/#add-types-to-allowed-child-types-action

Comment: @RezkarJs I put some examples to my answer

Comment: Sorry, it just replace default AllowedChildTypes with File only, i need default + File, how?

Comment: @RezkarJs did you try the second example? The AddAllowedChildTypes action do not replace the type list, just add the one you've set as parameter

Comment: It's invalid code, i've tried this code
> Task<dynamic> task = workspace.AddAllowedChildTypes(new { contentTypes = new string[] { "File" } });
But default AllowedChildTypes just replaced with File only.